# How to filter rows from table without caring word cases

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have used following code to filter rows from table ...

```
  $("#searchInput").live("keyup", function () {

         //split the current value of searchInput
         var data = this.value.split(" ");
         //create a jquery object of the rows
         var jo = $("#movies").find("tr");
         if (this.value == "") {
             jo.show();
             return;
         }
         //hide all the rows
         jo.hide();

         //Recusively filter the jquery object to get results.
         jo.filter(function (i, v) {
             var $t = $(this);
             for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
                 if ($t.is(":contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
                     return true;
                 }
             }
             return false;
         })
         //show the rows that match.
.show();
     }).focus(function () {
         this.value = "";
         $(this).css({
             "color": "black"
         });
         $(this).unbind('focus');
     }).css({
         "color": "#C0C0C0"
     });
```

My table rows has data like abc,Abc,ABC. When I search from character 'a' my function returns rows that have only small character a.. I want all data which starts with 'a' should be returned ... please help me..

Comment: I doubt your following code might not work as the data is actually contained in TD and not TR!
`if ($t.is(":contains('" + data[d] + "')")) 
    {
     return true;                 }`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**.indexOf()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [**.toLowerCase()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

```
jo.filter(function (i, v) {
    var $t = $(this);
    for(var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
        var text = $t.text().toLowerCase();  //Get text and convert it to lower case
        if(text.indexOf(data[d].toLowerCase()) > -1) { //Use indexOf method to check that text contains input text
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}).show();
```

### EDIT:

As per comment *how can i search only first and third td of tr???*

```
jo.filter(function (i, v) {
    var $t = $(this);
    for(var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
        //Get text and convert it to lower case
        var firstTdText = $t.find('td:eq(0)').text().toLowerCase();
        var thirdTdText = $t.find('td:eq(2)').text().toLowerCase();

        //Use indexOf method to check that text contains input text
        if(firstTdText.indexOf(data[d].toLowerCase()) > -1 || thirdTdText.indexOf(data[d].toLowerCase()) > -1) { 
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}).show();
```

Comment: Thanks It workes perfectly. Can you please help me that how can i search only first and third td of tr???

Comment: @social, From perform point of view move `var firstTdText = ..` and `var thirdTdText =` out of loop

Answer (score 0):

You should compare both strings either transferring whole string to uppercase or lowercase